# Magento 2 EE considerably slower that Magento 2 CE

Tags: magento2, development

Our developers are complaining that Magento2 EE is considerably slower that the CE version. Is there a reason for this?

Is there an ideal local work environment that is recommended with Magento2 EE?

For example: Core i5/ 8gb?

Comment: Have you set up Varnish? And split databases?

Comment: I installed M2 on DO $5 VPS. It have just 512 mb of ram and one shared cpu. For me the performance looks good enough. Can you check that you have performance better then me site https://mage2-demo.tk/